# Bazel incremental build results

Tags: build, bazel

I have a code base with multiple modules that I want to build with Bazel.
There are some common libraries and applications in my build and not every application will use the same common libraries.

If I have a previous build by Bazel and changeset on a common library used by application A, but not application B and build from the root with Bazel, will only the common library and application A be built and tested and result in a new binary?

It says on the site that `Bazel only rebuilds what is necessary` and I want to verify that it's this that is meant.

I could just test this myself of course, and I will if I don't get an answer and answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have a changeset on a common library used by application A, but not application B and build from the root with Bazel, will only the common library and application A be built and tested and result in a new binary?

Yes, as long as there are no transitive dependency edges from B to the common library (e.g. B -> A -> common library, or B -> common library). To be precise, this means that no output files of `B` depends on a command line that depends on input files from the command library.

Note that `bazel build //...` builds everything. You can run `bazel build //package/to:A` and it will ignore `B` if `B` is not required in `A`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly if I `bazel build //...` with only a change in B, only B will be built? And if the change would be on the library, the library and A will be built? Of course with the premise previous build artifacts exist.

Comment: Yes, and anything that depends on B's files. For the second case, yes, as long as B does not depend on the library and A.